# nokogiri with :after css selector

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I've the following html:

```html
<li><a href="/stumbler/millisami/tag/company/" class="">
  <span class="right">69</span>
  company</a>
</li>
```

and I want to scrap the text after the span tag, i.e. "company"

So, when I tried

```rb
doc.at_css("span:after")
```

the no method error :after is thrown.
How to use pseudo selectors with Nokogiri??

Answer (score 2):

According to the CSS 2.1 standard, [the ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used *to insert generated content* before or after an element's content](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#before-and-after), but not to per se select elements.

You can workaround this shortcoming using

```rb
doc.at_css("span").next_sibling()
```